# Did a Jewish prisoner write this quote about God and forgiveness?

Tags: history, quotes, world-war-ii

According to a number of social media sites, including [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/quotes/comments/1e18ys/):

> “If there is a God, He will have to beg my forgiveness.” — A phrase that was carved on the walls of a concentration camp cell during WWII by a Jewish prisoner.

Is this attribution correct?

Comment: Minnor nitpick, but nobody knows if the author was Jewish. The quote wasn't signed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**It's very likely correct.** The correct original quote should be:

> Wenn es einen Gott gibt muß er mich um Verzeihung bitten.

It is a quote that supposedly appears on the walls of the jails of Mauthausen concentration camp, according to the documentary they show to people at the camp tours.

I have found [many](http://www.boblucky.com/Biking/Danube/day3.htm) [anecdotal](http://www.travelblog.org/Europe/Austria/Upper-Austria/Mauthausen/blog-678100.html) [confirmations](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Nx4HU0Fexj0C&lpg=PA165&dq=%22if%20there%20is%20a%20god%22%20%22beg%20my%20forgiveness%22&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q=%22if%20there%20is%20a%20god%22%20%22beg%20my%20forgiveness%22&f=false) [of](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iUqKafcKRukC&lpg=PA149&dq=%22If+there+is+a+god%22+%22beg+my+forgiveness%22&pg=PA149&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22If%20there%20is%20a%20god%22%20%22beg%20my%20forgiveness%22&f=false) [this](http://betsy.murphy00.tripod.com/Europe/WesternEurope.html).

I finally managed to track down a copy of said documentary, unfortunately in Italian, and it does make that claim. Given that is shown in the same concentration camp, I have no reason to doubt it's true.

From a [transcript](http://ospitiweb.indire.it/~copc0001/ebraismo/mauthaus.htm):

> Nel carcere del campo, detto bunker, si impidocchiano i detenuti per esperimenti con gli antiparassitari, ma il carcere del campo serve anzitutto per isolare i prigionieri. La Gestapo del campo vuole estorcere confessioni e tiene i detenuti nelle celle, per bastonarli a sangue, per torturarli: per molti questa gabbia è l'ultima tappa della vita.
>
> Mentre, di solito, sulle pareti delle celle ci sono scritte di speranza o testimonianze di uno spirito sveglio che si ribella alla prostrazione, qui troviamo l'ultimo monologo, segno di avvilimento, di disperazione, di morte imminente.
>
> > Dio mio perché mi hai abbandonato?
> >
> > Piegarsi significa mentire
> >
> > Se esiste un dio, deve chiedermi perdono
>
> Queste scritte sono state ritrovate, dopo il 1945, sui muri delle celle.

(translation)

> In the prison of the camp, called the 'bunker', they give lice to prisoners for experiments with pesticides, but the camp's prison serves primarily to isolate the prisoners. The camp's Gestapo wants to extort confessions and holds the prisoners in cells, to beat them bloody, to torture them: for many this cage is the last stage of life.
>
> While, usually, on the walls of the cells there are writings expressing hope, or testimonies of a wakeful spirit which rebels against bowing down, here we find the last monologue, a sign of discouragement, despair, of imminent death .
>
> > My God why have you forsaken me?
> >
> > To bend means to lie
> >
> > If there is a god, he must ask me forgiveness
>
> These writings were found, after 1945, on the walls of the cells.

The documentary is available on YouTube: http://youtu.be/8r50t7148sA?t=19m20s

[image]

Given that the documentary is indeed showing the walls of the Mauthausen jails while this is described by they are (freshly) painted white, I think that the writings are not there anymore, so finding a picture will likely be almost impossible.

There is no proof that these were written by a Jewish prisoner:

- It is not claimed by the original source. The documentary doesn't say it was a *signed* message, nor that it was written in Hebrew.
- It was in the jails, not in the Jewish barracks, which excludes assuming authorship based on location.
- As mentioned in the comments, only [a minority of the Mauthausen inmates were Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauthausen-Gusen_concentration_camp#Inmates).

Yet it is possible that some of the authors were Jewish:

- The first writing appears in [Psalm 22:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2022&version=KJV) as well as in the Gospels.
- The second writing, "Sich fügen heißt lügen", appears in a 1920 poem titled "[The Prisoner](http://www.gedichte.eu/ex/muehsam/brennende-erde/der-gefangene.php)", written by a [German-Jewish antimilitarist anarchist poet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_M%C3%BChsam).

---

Update: I've found on the official Mauthausen Memorial web site,  a German and English translation of the documentary which is called "Rückkehr unerwünscht (return undesirable)". The interesting part is still at 19m20s.

- English: http://en.mauthausen-memorial.at/db/admin/de/showvideodetail256.php?cvideo=39&cbereich=1&cthema=347
- German: http://www.mauthausen-memorial.at/db/admin/de/showvideodetail256.php?cvideo=16&cbereich=1&cthema=347

Comment: Does the original German quote translates to "If there is a God, He will have to beg my forgiveness" exactly?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed [google is your friend](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Wenn%20es%20einen%20Gott%20gibt%20mu%C3%9F%20er%20mich%20um%20Verzeihung%20bitten.)

Comment: Google translate isn't a good source to get the "Exact" translation. As many times a phrase or a sentence will have a meaning that is greater than just its literal translation, Something that a human speaking the language may understand but a machine will not, for example "J'accuse" has a far greater meaning than "I accuse" even though they are the same phrase in different languages.

Comment: The first message could be Jewish, as the line appears in [Psalm 22:1](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2022&version=KJV) in addition to the Gospels.

Comment: How do you understand/translate the word "sveglio" in that context?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed right, but there is also the fact that the documentary Italian dubbing concurs with Google. Given two different translations coincide, I would assume the answer is "yes" unless there's reason to the contrary.

Comment: @ChrisW literally: "awake", *cf.* "vigil".

Comment: @jwodder I will correct my answer.

Comment: Also, the [Mauthausen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauthausen-Gusen_concentration_camp#Inmates) complex held mostly non Jews, and the Jews that were brought there eventually were mostly Dutch and Hungarian, so they would probably not write in German, but in their language or Yiddish, please add this to the answer.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed Don't you think that "J'accuse" and "I accuse" have the same meaning? IMO "[J'accuse!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J'accuse)" has more meaning only in that it has historical resonance/lineage. IMO it's a good literal translation from German to English. I find few allusions to it using Google, except in the context of Mauthausen (and from someone in the context of their losing their baby). Would you ask on [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/) whether the phrase has a significance or resonance in the Jewish tradition, or should be attributed to a Jewish writer?

Comment: @ChrisW, I gave it as an example of a meaning that isn't conveyed by automatic translation programs. Machine translation are famous for translating wrong, so I don't trust them when I'm looking for an exact translation. I wanted to check that nothing got lost or added in the translation as [sometines happens](http://www.lackuna.com/2012/04/13/5-historically-legendary-translation-blunders/).

Comment: @IlyaMelamed “If there is a God, He will have to beg my forgiveness.” is how it's translated in the English-language version of the documentary (presumably by a professional human translator). It's also how I read the German: with possible minor variations e.g. "ask" instead of "beg", and "pardon" instead of "forgiveness" - there are various idioms in English like "I beg your pardon", "please forgive me", "I am sorry" - perhaps a modern non-literal colloquial might be something like "he'll have to say '[sorry](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/Verzeihung)' to me".